# JQuery find text nodes with not selector on nested elements work only with .contents() and filter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Please help me understand why this is happening.

(UPDATE) TL;DR:
nested elements' text will be included when using find with not(NESTED_ELEMENT) selector but will be excluded when using find with not(NESTEDT_ELEMENT)+contents+filter(TEXT_NODE).

I want to get the text from a page but to exclude some elements.
For the simplicity, I have excluded `<p>` element only (and descendants) but when I use the `text()`, I'm also getting the text in the excluded element.
When I filter the results with `contents()` to include only text nodes, only then the not selector is "working" by not returning the text from the excluded elements. Please see image below with the code used:

[image]
Why isn't it working without using `contents()`?

Thanks.

For your convenience:

The URL that I tested on is [this one](http://accessiblehtmlheadings.com/).

The code that gives me the excluded element's text:

```
$('body').find(':not(p, p *)').text()
```

The code that gives me the desired text (excluded element's text not present):

```
$('body').find(':not(p, p *)').contents().filter(function(){return this.nodeType == 3}).text()
```

And here's the HTML part from the URL. As you can see, there's a `<p>` element there and As described, I want to get the text from this HTML but to exclude some elements (p was selected for simplicity, there will be lots more rules in production).

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                    <header id="header" role="banner" class="jumbotron">
                        <h1>
                            <img src="/img/icon/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png" class="offscreen" alt="">
                            <i class="icon-html5" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="offscreen">HTML 5</span>
                            <span>Semantics and Accessibility: <span class="subheader">Heading Structure</span></span>
                        </h1>
                        <p class="lead" id="lead_content">The more you understand the specification, the more you'll realize there are more right 
                        ways to implement <em>proper</em> semantic HTML markup than wrong. Thinking in terms of web accessibility can provide direction.</p>
                    </header>
                </div>
```

Comment: Add your HTML code please.

Comment: You can find everything in the attached photo. The URL that I did my tests on and the JS code that I've used in the console. All in there.

Comment: Can include actual `html` text , `js` tried at Question ? Not able to "see" text of image clearly , here

Comment: OK, It's been added to the question above.

Comment: _"OK, It's been added to the question above."_ ? Where ? No `html` appear at Question ? What is requirement ?

Comment: There you go, I also added the HTML section.

Comment: @mrgoos using `$('body').find(':not(p, p *)').text()` you are still returning `<div class="col-lg-12">` text

Comment: @A.Wolff, I know. I just want to exclude the p element. How come that it works with contents()? Is it because the fact that with contents() I get each of the element "separately" and this is why the not selector is working in that case? It's very weird because the contents() is called after find().

Comment: @mrgoos Is requirement to return `"HTML 5"` , `"Semantics and Accessibility:"` , `"Heading Structure"` as text from `.col-lg-12` element ?

Comment: @mrgoos if you check in your console what returns `$('body').find(':not(p, p *)').contents()` you'll see that the `:not()` isn't excluding P element, because it is descendant of DIV element. That's waht you are doing in filter() method which exclud text of P element. That's said, you could use: `$('body').clone().find('p').remove().end().text().trim()`

Comment: @A.Wolff, this is true that you can see p element in the contents result BUT it is being filtered and its text will not show up at the end result. If I won't use the not selector. for example I'll use find('*'), then, the text from the p element WILL show up at the end result.

Comment: @mrgoos _"this is true that you can see p element in the contents result BUT it is being filtered and its text will not show up at the end result. If I won't use the not selector. for example I'll use find('*'), then, the text from the p element WILL show up at the end result."_ ? Does requirement also include using `.not()` method ? Perhaps several approaches to achieving expected result , `.clone()` parent node , `.remove()` nodes not expected at result one option ; original parent node `html` should not be affected - unless requirement is to alter original `html` ?

Comment: @guest271314, no, there's not an essence to use not. This whole question is about understanding how come this code is working (contents()) + filter since as A.Wolff wrote, I still get the p element after the contents() BUT after filtering, I DON'T get the p element's text which is exactly the desired result. So the not selector is working after all in some bizarre way. I'm trying to understand why. I know that other methods can result the same requirements, that's not the issue.

Comment: @mrgoos I've not that much time to go further and check what's going on but now i get your point. That's quite confusing indeed...

Comment: @mrgoos _"So the not selector is working after all in some bizarre way."_ Not certain interpret comment correctly ? Does `js` at Question return expected results ?

Comment: @A.Wolff _"but now i get your point. That's quite confusing indeed... "_ Which portion ?

Comment: @guest271314 Sorry, i meant i understand now exactly what is your question. What is confusing me is the same that confused you in OP but i've no idea why this behaves like that.

Comment: @guest271314 - please go over my answers, I believe that you'll get the point as well.
There's an unexpected behavior in this post about nested elements, as demonstrated.

Comment: @mrgoos `$('body').find(':not(p, p *)').text()` returns jQuery collection at both `.find` and `.text` first element returned would be `<div class="col-lg-12">` which includes `p` ; `.text()` iterates each element passed to it . If observe `console` , last iteration actually excludes `p` , where last output of `.text()` would be `"HTML 5Semantics and Accessibility: Heading StructureHeading Structure "` - with `p`  , `p`  child nodes excluded; see http://jsfiddle.net/c56fv4oc/ , http://jsfiddle.net/c56fv4oc/1/ http://jsfiddle.net/c56fv4oc/2/ . Note `i` , `this` within `.text()` callback function

Comment: @guest271314 - that's the whole point.
In this jsfiddle, the text from the excluded element is retrieved: http://jsfiddle.net/c56fv4oc/.
BUT, by using contents()+filter(), it won't (your 2ns jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/c56fv4oc/1/. This is unexpected since p is found in contents() result as well but ignored.

Comment: `p` is still child node of `.col-lg-12` , `.col-lg-12` does not have `P` node name . `.col-lg-12`  is iterated first , before its child nodes - where `P` is found  is iterated . `P` is excluded when checking its node name against original selector when its node is iterated

Comment: @guest271314, but p holds a text node which is not being ignored in the 1st jsfiddle and IS being ignored in the 2nd.

Comment: @mrgoos If add `console.log(res)` to first example http://jsfiddle.net/c56fv4oc/3/, note that `p` is excluded from final results of returned jQuery object. However, since original selector is "greedy" , e.g., `$('body').find(':not(p, p *)')` , `.col-lg-12` is iterated first - before reaching - and excluding - its `p` child node - and returns `textContent` of `.col-lg-12` - which includes its `p` child node `textContent`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91303/discussion-between-mrgoos-and-guest271314).

Comment: @mrgoos As i understand it, this is what happen: ↓↓↓

Comment: @mrgoos  ↑↑↑ using `$('body').find(':not(p, p *)')` you get all elements which are not `p` or descendant of `p`. Then using `.contents()` you get all the content of these elements including their respective textnode. But as you know, this include `p` element because child of `header` element BUT not textnode of `p` element (you don't get the content of `p` element). Then filtering it using `.filter(function(){return this.nodeType == 3})` you get only the textnodes which doesn't include the content (textnode) of `p` element. Maybe this help: http://jsfiddle.net/s8ts9jvo/

Comment: @A.Wolff, you are right of course. But this is what so strange about it. Instead of p element not showing up at all I get the p element without its content. So if, for some reason, I want to count how many valid nodes I have in 'body' (+ using a selector for my needs), p will be counted (bad) and its content will not (good).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.clone()` , `.remove()` , `.text()`

```js
var filtered = $(".col-lg-12").clone();
filtered.find("p").remove();

console.log(filtered.text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <header id="header" role="banner" class="jumbotron">
    <h1>
                            <img src="/img/icon/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png" class="offscreen" alt="">
                            <i class="icon-html5" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="offscreen">HTML 5</span>
                            <span>Semantics and Accessibility: <span class="subheader">Heading Structure</span></span>
                        </h1>
    <p class="lead" id="lead_content">The more you understand the specification, the more you'll realize there are more right ways to implement <em>proper</em> semantic HTML markup than wrong. Thinking in terms of web accessibility can provide direction.</p>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but as I wrote in my post's comment, I know that other methods can result the same requirements, that's not the issue. I want to understand why by using contents()+filter and the text() - the not selector is working but by using find only and then text() => it doesn't.

Comment: @mrgoos Still not following , here. Can create jsfiddle with both versions described to demonstrate ?

Comment: The point is that nested elements' text will be included when using find with not(NESTED_ELEMENT) selector but will be excluded when using find with not(NESTEDT_ELEMENT)+contents+filter(TEXT_NODE). You follow?